# Edit link in email updates box is not working in Favorite Tags filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, email-notification, tag-filters

On https://stackexchange.com/filters, I have my favorite tags filter. I setup email notifications for it and now I'm thinking I overdid it on the frequency.

Trying to change the settings, I clicked on the edit link in the email notifications box to the right, except nothing happens. There are no JavaScript errors and the HTML for the link is simply `<a class="edit">edit</a>`.

This seems like unfinished planned feature.

**Update:**
Using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m
Same on Firefox 23.0.1

[image: Screenshot]

Both edit links are not working.

**Further Update**
Events capture:
[image]

**Update 2014-02-03:**
Here's what the subscription tab in the network profile looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this a couple days ago. You can now edit existing subscriptions to My Sites and Favorite Tags filters, as well as unsubscribe from emails for those filters.