# Why is email subscription information scattered throughout the site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, email-notification

Currently, inbox notification email settings are located at the very bottom of the supercollider menu. Newsletter subscriptions are handled on stackexchange.com. "Other" email notification settings are located under the preferences link on the user profile page.

These settings should be consolidated.

Comment: New record for the quickest [status-completed] ever: 0 seconds!

Comment: Also, I'm aware we need a little more padding on things. Coming tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct, sir, and indeed we have consolidated email settings in the preferences tab of the user profile page.

Unfortunately, since newsletter subscriptions are on a different backend, we couldn't consolidate them right now. However, we've added a link so that all of your email settings are reachable from the same place.

[image]

Comment: Every time I see that you've made a post I'm glad, because it's a reliable sign that some annoying or unpolished aspect of the site has been improved. Please keep being awesome!

Comment: @JeremyonVacation I appreciate that. This is just a small one, though.

Comment: Nice! While you're at it, can you take a look at [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196479/152859)? :-)