# Delete button for tags fell down

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, design

Ironically posting a [failed bug report/feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199097/152859) led me to find a true bug when editing it:

> [image]

Can those poor X's be placed back in the middle where they belong? :)

Comment: Yep, same here in Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m

Comment: @Bart yeah, the culprit is `margin-top: 7px;` added to `delete-tag` class. Standard CSS.

Comment: It's not just the delete button that fell.. the entire tag's drowning :-(.

Comment: @ben good catch, I was too focused on the X!

Comment: Sshhhh, you're not supposed to solve it for them @ShaWizDowArd.

Comment: @Bart this [won't be the first time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196479/edit-link-in-email-updates-box-defective#comment624233_196479). :)

Comment: Come on over and spin the wheel. Has to go around at least once. If not, it doesn't count, and there's no do-overs.

Comment: @animuson unless I'm very wrong the [meta-tag:tag-suggestions] tag is for the tag editor... the bug is only in that editor not with the tags or editing process itself. Maybe [meta-tag:tag-suggestions] should be renamed to [meta-tag:tag-editor] to be less confusing?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [meta-tag:tag-suggestions] is for the popup that *suggests* tags to you based on what you've typed and the tag suggestions that appear below the box when creating a question, not for the edit box itself. The system isn't suggesting anything to you in that scenario.

Comment: @animuson oh my, blonde moment! Don't you think we better add [meta-tag:tag-editor] then? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The problem with that is people will confuse it with [meta-tag:tag-editor-badge] which is synonymized with [meta-tag:editing-badges]. I don't really see what's wrong with the [meta-tag:editing] + [meta-tag:tags] combination. You're editing the tags... Simple enough. In fact, [meta-tag:retagging] is synonymized with [meta-tag:tags].

Comment: @hjpotter92: the issue is not only with inline-tag-editing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The delete button has fallen and couldn't get up. I blame its alcohol dependency.

I have now enrolled it with the AA and things should start to get back to normal as it goes through its 12 steps.

Comment: Sad sad story... cheers for being brave enough to admit the addiction! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it took forever for it to admit it had a problem. I think this Meta post (and the dupes) is what finally made the difference. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Oded - Still need to fix [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199103/delete-button-for-tags-fell-down#comment631934_199103). The bottom of the tag touches the border.

Comment: @hims056 - I noticed. It is Meta theme specific, I believe (to do with the extra border around the mandatory tags) - as such a bit lower priority (not pun intended)