# Tags went through an extreme diet

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

After [getting drunk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199185/152859), the poor tags now went through an extreme diet all over Meta. It's easily visible in the "Recent Tags" view:

> [image]

I went back in time to [September 21<sup>st</sup>](http://web.archive.org/web/20130921200237/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to take this screenshot of good and healthy tags:

> [image]

Can they please eat properly again to gain some weight?

Comment: Maybe they are getting ready for the holidays so they don't have as much weight to lose come January.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They needed a diet, so they would have the same height as their non-required brethren.

Strangely enough, they only appear to be on diet in the tag editor now.

Comment: But it looks... much less nice.. then before. So if I'll start feature request asking to put the old design back will it be rejected for sure?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - never say never. I made the change because the design was interfering with the inline tag editor (tags on MSO were still lined at the bottom).

Comment: Can't you separate the tag editor view from the general view? Maybe it's just me but the change was... overwhelming!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Frankly, didn't consider that to be an issue, but will look at fixing it, just for you.

Comment: Just don't blame me if something worse happens, lol! ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - You mean like a black hole appearing and sucking in the Earth?

Comment: Oh no, such black hole would surely be the doing of the [Void Which Binds](http://hyperioncantos.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Earth)! :D

Comment: By the way thanks for the fix, or more accurately undoing your change - surely a good candidate for the fastest fixed bug.